# rxjs: filter observable by json field

Tags: json, reactive-programming, rxjs, observable

I have a observable created based on websocket event.

```
Observable.fromEvent<Response>(websocket, 'message');
```

it contains json objects like

```
{"id": "A", "value": 123}
{"id": "B", "value": 456}
{"id": "C", "value": 789}
{"id": "A", "value": 321}
```

Now, I'm going to create three observables, events in each of them have same id. (Eg. observable 1 contains only events with `"id": "A"`) so that subscriber who only cares about `"id": "A"` can subscribe the specific one.

So, I created observable like

```
public GetMonitorData = (): Observable<Response> => {
     Observable.fromEvent<Response>(websocket, 'message')
           .filter(function (result, idx) {
                return JSON.parse(result)['id'] === 'A'; //syntax error at here
            });
}
```

and subscribe like

```
GetMonitorData().subscribe((result) => {
      // I expect all subscribed events at here are of same 'id'
      let parsedResponse = JSON.parse(result.data);
      this.updateStats(parsedResponse);
});
```

Edit: I expect I can filter based on the `'id'` of json objects, but `return JSON.parse(result)['id'] === 'A';` complains `Argument of type Response is not assignable to parameter of type string`. So, I don't know how to extract the `'id'` from Observable's event and use it to filter events.

Put it in another way, I have incoming observable like

```
--A--B--A--C--B--C--->
```

and I want to create three observables like

```
--A--A-->
--B--B-->
--C--C-->
```

where `A, B, C` are events whose JSON `'id'` value is `A, B, C`, respectively. I don't know how to filter based the `'id'` value, since the event is observable, `JSON.parse(result)['id']` can't extract it.

Comment: What does 'work as expected' mean? Do you have an example of how you are subscribing to this and what is not working?

Comment: Please have a look at stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidelines to deal with 'it does not work' questions. Basically post a minimally verifiable example that reproduces the error, and post the expected behaviour and how it is different from the current behavior.

Comment: @paulpdaniels I added code for subscribing the observable

Comment: @user3743222 sorry for the ambiguity, I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to parse an `Object`. A quick look at the [`WebSocket` `MessageEvent` specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent) tells us that there is a `data` property that holds the payload message.

Meaning you should need:

```
 //I am fairly certain Response is not what WebSocket returns so I changed this to 
 //MessageEvent, but I don't have a TS compiler to try this with right now.
 Observable.fromEvent<MessageEvent>(websocket, 'message')
       .filter(function (result, idx) {
            return JSON.parse(result.data)['id'] === 'A'; //syntax error at here
        });
```

To further answer your question you can indeed split the streams up like this, but I would put the parsing into the `fromEvent` selector to avoid the overhead of parsing the JSON for each subscription:

```
 var source = Observable.fromEvent<MessageEvent>(websocket, 'message', (e) => JSON.parse(result.data));

 var sourceA = source.filter(result => result.id === 'A');
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Very helpful explanation. I'll add your book to my list as well.